# VMWare Shared Storage not Syncing File Changes

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, storage, vmware-workstation

So, I am experimenting with a couple VM's.
Both are fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installs, no updates, no vmware tools.

Both are able to read and write to this `SharedTest.vmdk`, while both are running.  What I am finding is if I `touch` a file to the first while shell'd into it, the file will not show on the second vm, until I reboot it.

How can I make sure both VM's sync this file change?

(I have googled this and came up with the config below, that at least allows the storage to get attached to both concurrently)

**NOTE:** SharedTest.vmdk is an ext4 formatted mount on both VM's, but is stored on a NTFS drive.

**NOTE 2:** I am using VMWare Workstation 10

My Config for both VM's contain:

```
# Attached Shared Disk
scsi0:1.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:1.fileName = "D:\TempVMs\SharedDisk.vmdk"
scsi0:1.mode = "independent-persistent"
scsi0:1.shared = "TRUE"
scsi0:1.sharing = "multi-writer"
scsi0:1.redo = ""

# Disk Properties.
disk.locking = "FALSE"
diskLib.dataCacheMaxSize = "0"
diskLib.dataCacheMaxReadAheadSize = "0"
diskLib.dataCacheMinReadAheadSize = "0"
diskLib.dataCachePageSize = "0"
diskLib.dataMaxUnsyncedWrites = "0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how shared storage works.

The filesystem you are using (ext4) is not a cluster file system. As such, it can only be mounted read/write by a single system at a time. The fact that the volume can be made accessible to multiple systems at the same time does not change this basic tenet of the filesystem.

If you need both systems to be able to write at the same time, you will either need to switch to a true cluster-aware filesystem or else mount the fs on a single system and export it to the others via NFS or the like.